# What is best approach to show the component page in popup-modal window without header and footer?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, development, templates

I have developed a custom component that displays some information. I want to show the same information in modal popup window without header and footer information. what should be best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haven't done this for awhile, but these steps should do it:

1. Add `JHTML::_('behavior.modal');` near the top of the view
2. Add `class="modal"` to any links you want to open in a modal window
3. Add `&tmpl=component` the the link you want in a popup

**Note**: I answered, then deleted this because upon trying it with a J3.3 installation, I got some javascript errors, so I can't say for sure that it remains the right way of doing it or is an issue with our template.

Comment: Just a note that `'behavior.modal'` will utilise Mootools rather than Bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Modal plugin from Regular Labs to do something like you describe. There is a free version and a Pro version available.
Their plugin is easy to use and with minimum reading of their tutorial, anyone can use them.

I am not affiliated with them, nor do I have any kind of relation with them.

Link: [Modal](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modals)