# Content Modal Popup fails due to Javascript error

Tags: javascript

Using my own answer for [What is best approach to show the component page in popup-modal window without header and footer?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/what-is-best-approach-to-show-the-component-page-in-popup-modal-window-without-h), I mentioned that I was getting JS errors, so when as I further investigate, they persist:

```
TypeError:Argument 1 of Node.contains does not implement interface Node
http://mysite/mediamedia/system/js/modal.js
```

**Update:** *Turns out to be a Firefox issue, not Joomla, so pondering deleting the question pending resolution.*

I put this lines directly into `index.php` of the Protostar template of a fresh default installation of Joomla 3.2.4 and tried it that way.

```
<?php
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
?>
<a class='modal' href='index.php?option=com_content&view=article&tmpl=component&id=10&Itemid=180'>Modal link</a>
```

A small popup does appear, but contains nothing - has anyone dealt with this before? - I'm stumped.

Comment: what happens if you simply load an element in the modal rather than a component view...do you still get the same error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean or how to try it ... made the link go to google.com instead, and no error, but infinite spinner in the popup

Comment: Hmm ok, and what if you add `&format=raw` to the end of the URL?

Comment: The aha moment...I think it's Firebug, or at least in Firefox

Comment: I'll give this a test myself when I'm back from work if you still have issues

Comment: Well, it is just Firefox v34.0.5 on a brand new PC with Win8.1 - have disabled every plugin and extension and it persists.

Comment: I always use FF beta (currently 35) and developer edition so will be interesting to compare.

Comment: Its generally the least troublesome of the browsers, so count on it work correctly there, and adjust for the others.

Comment: GDP, Did you ever figure out this what the issue was?

Comment: I did, but frankly, don't recall what it was....I'm certain that it was a conflict of files, but the details completely elude me now.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Try:

- Turn on Joomla's Error Reporting and see if there is any error message
- Disable Adblock if you have it
- Open the link in a separate tab and see if it's valid (ie Joomla does not throw an error)
- Use absolute URL instead of relative